# Emailing based on a combobox selection

Tags: email, ms-access, combobox, vba

I am trying to send an email based on a combobox selection and a click of a submit button. I get a type mismatch error. I used select case because I will be adding more than one combobox with names to the form.

```
Dim StrEmail as String
Select Case Me.cmbOwner2

Case Is = "AV"
    If StrEmail Is Null Then
        StrEmail = "dan.moses@yahoo.com"
    Else
        StrEmail = StrEmail & "," & "dan.moses@yahoo.com"


Case Is = "ENG"
    If StrEmail Is Null Then
        StrEmail = "brianna.cates@yahoo.com"
    Else
        StrEmail = StrEmail & "," & "brianna.cates@yahoo.com"
    End If

End Select

DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "StrEmail", "", _
  "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Avoid using if strEmail = null, or ifnull(strEmail).

Instead, do either if strEmail="", or if len(strEmail)=0

Reason: when you declare a String variable in VBA, testing it for null will return false. So in your code, it is jumping directly to this part:

```
Else
StrEmail = StrEmail & "," & "dan.moses@yahoo.com"
```

which means your string of recipients starts with a comma.

2) Use a semicolon instead of a comma as the separator for recipients in Outlook.

Comment: Ok I got it to work but the email addresses arent populating in the email in the To box Stremail pops up instead :/

Comment: Remove the quotes around StrEmail. Should be like this:

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, StrEmail, "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"